# Question about generic point of a scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have a simple question.

Let $X$ be a scheme (can have additional property). And let $Z \subset X$ be a subset. Consider the closure $\bar{Z}$, viewed as a closed reduced subscheme.

Now, let $Y \subseteq \bar{Z}$ be an irreducible component of $\bar{Z}$ with generic point $Y =\bar{\{ \eta\}}$.

Then $\eta \in Z$?

If not, when?

Motivation for this question is trial of understanding next proof of theorem (Gortz's Algebraic Geometry, Theorem 14.130) :

[image]

[image]

I'm now trying to understand the underlined statement. There, the theorem 5.22-(3) is,

**Theorem 5.22**. Let $X$ be an irreducible $k$-scheme locally of finite type with generic point $\eta$.

(3) Let $f : Y\to X$ be a morphism of $k$-schemes locally of finite type such that $f(Y)$ contains the generic point $\eta$ of $X$. Then $\operatorname{dim}Y \ge \operatorname{dim}X$.

My first attempt to understand the underlined statement is as follows :

If $\operatorname{dim}Y_1 \le \operatorname{dim}C$ , then as the underlined statement, it suffices to show that $\operatorname{dim}C < \operatorname{dim} U$. So we show that $\operatorname{dim}Y_1 \le \operatorname{dim}C$. Since $\operatorname{dim}Y_1$ is the supremum of all dimensions of its irreducible components, we now fix an arbitrary irreducible component $Y \subseteq Y_1$ and show that $\operatorname{dim}Y \le \operatorname{dim}C$. Let $\eta$ be the generic point of the $Y$.

Let $f :=pr_1 : U \times_k X \times_k X \to U$ as in the proof. Now consider the restriction $g : C \cap f^{-1}(Y) \to Y$ of $f$. Since the immersion is locally of finite type, we can show that $C \cap f^{-1}(Y)$ and $Y$ are $k$-schemes locally of finite type. Note that $\eta \in Y \subseteq Y_1:=\bar{f(C)}$.

So, if our question is true, then $\eta \in f(C)$. So the image of $g$ contains the $\eta$. So we can apply the above Theorem 5.22-(3) ; i.e.,

$$ \operatorname{dim}Y \le \operatorname{dim}(C\cap f^{-1}(Y)) \le \operatorname{dim}(C)$$

And we are done.

And, is our question true? Can anyone helps?

Comment: I'm not sure. What if you take $Z \subset \mathbb{A}^1_\mathbb{C}$ be some infinite set of closed points? Then, $\overline{Z} =  \mathbb{A}^1_\mathbb{C}$ but $Z$ doesn't contain the generic point, right?

Comment: O.K. I see. I don't know how to break through, regarding my original motivation. Anyway thank you!